# What is the Proguard Rule for CircularReveal Effect Library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Im using the following library
**https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal**
I was wondering what rule I need to pt in Proguard. 
I declared the dependency like this

```
compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForUAT'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".Debug"
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // android support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your app `build.gradle` and top level `build.gradle`

Comment: @bertrand Martel posted